# How can I access the HDD of a Microsoft Surface 1.0 table?

Tags: hardware-failure

After a few freight transport trips, our Microsoft Surface died. Everything leads to a hard disk drive hardware failure, as it doesn't even show up at POST anymore, thus leading to a "No boot device detected" BIOS error.

After looking on the web, I could only find a manual for servicing the lamps and accessing the I/O ports.

What is the best procedure for accessing the PC hardware located inside the Microsoft Surface 1.0, since we have to replace the HDD ?

I was planning on flashing an image that was created on day one, upon receiving the Microsoft Surface, "just in case", onto a new hard disk drive and plug this drive right into the internal PC, and boot it up.

Any lead would be appreciated.

The Microsoft Surface we own is long out of warranty.

Comment: I think you might be on your own here - how many of the Surfaces were ever made?